# Native Array, Stack, ArrayList or List for creating 'low pass' filter

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, arraylist

Trying to create a type of low pass filter where I constantly average the previous 10 float values. Not sure whether to use builtin arrays (native .NET arrays), the .NET Stack operator, or perhaps an ArrayList or List.

In pseudocode I need to

1- Define the array or Stack containing 10 floats

2- Every update Push a new value to the Array, Stack, List

3- Check the length and if greater than10 remove the first or oldest float value from the Array, Stack, List

4- Get the average of all float values in the Array, Stack, List

5- Repeat steps 2-4

1st question Should I be using built in Arrays, Stack, ArrayList or List instead? I notice in the Stack documentation there is no method for removing the oldest (bottom)item from the stack, but perhaps I am missing something

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw(v=vs.100).aspx

What I need is all the functionality of the (Javascript only) Array class but in C#.

2nd Can anyone help with actual syntax using either approach? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the generic [`Queue<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/7977ey2c(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to store the values:

```
var queue = new Queue<float>();
queue.Enqueue(1.0f); // pushes new item
queue.Dequeue(); // removes oldest item
```

To obtain the average, use the LINQ `Average()` extension method:

```
var average = queue.Average();
```

Answer (score 2):

You've probably missed the Queue data structure. With it, you can put new elements to the end and delete old ones from the front.

Additionally, you don't need to look at all the elements in the array to compute the average if there are constantly 10 elements. Knowing the previous average you can compute the new average like this:

```
newAvg = oldAvg + (newElem - deletedElem)/10;
```

or more shortly:

```
avg += (newElem - deletedElem)/10;
```

Comment: From OP's Step #3, it sounds like the queue starts with 0 elements, which means there won't always be 10 elements in the queue, but I agree that Queue is the right data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Stacks are LIFO(Last In First Out).

If you want to remove the oldest value, then you'd want to use a queue (First In First Out).